# Is the cash from a buy out of mutually owned property taxable? Does capital gains apply?

Tags: capital-gains-tax

My ex boyfriend (of 6 years) and I co-owned a property we bought less than two years ago.

Upon our split...

We agreed that I would refinance the property, and buy him out (approx 150, 000)-removing his name from the title at close.

Is the money he rec'd from the buyout (since we owned the property less than 2 years) subject to capital gains?

Is the money considered taxable or reportable "income"?

Comment: What country/state?

Answer (score -1):

Single homeowners, such as your ex, can exclude $250k from capital gains taxation. But he would have had to live in the home for 2 of the last 5 years.

He didn't reach the 2 year mark, so he doesn't qualify for a full exclusion. He might qualify for a [partial exclusion](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523#en_US_2020_publink100073096), though. See the linked IRS publication.

Comment: This looks specific to USA. Other jurisdictions have different rules, so it might be better to wait for the OP to specify a location.